# Site recommendation for theoretical questions about Computer Organization and Architecture

Tags: support, site-recommendation

First of all, many people will backlash saying you should do some research. But believe me I did. But none of the blog posts or sites found by Google Search helped me with my problem. Hence I have come here asking for a site recommendation for my study related questions.

The situation is there was a multiple choice question asking to select which of the following among them is/are true. The subject is COA (Computer Organization and Architecture). And the question is purely theoretical. It was about the definitions of CO (Computer Organization) and CA (Computer Architecture). However the options provided got me very confused. My textbooks didn't help me either, because they are explaining the facts in more cumbersome words, and the exact definition is stated nowhere that I can find.

Hence my question, is there a site on SE network where such questions are on-topic? Also, is Academia the place where I should be visiting, since I thought this is more of a technical subject and might not be suitable therein? I think Stack Overflow and Software Engineering is not acceptable either, because there is no code.

Comment: @Rubén The post helped me zone in on two options, Computer Science and Theoretical Computer Science. Which one now? They look similar to me! TCS says that "if you aren't at least a graduate..visit CS". So I guess CS would do. Did I get it right?

Comment: You should spend some time reviewing the scope and guidelines of each site as well by searching for questions about the topics that you want to ask. It also might be helpful to look at their meta sites for questions about their scope and how to ask good questions.

Comment: Or just be bold and post your question on one of them and wait for feedback.

Comment: @Rubén I would consider both the suggestions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like Computer Science to me.

I suggest [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) where their [Help  page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> This site covers theoretical and applied computer science at any level, including but not limited to:
>
> ...
> computer architecture, networks